# What is the best way to merge two arrays (element + element), if elements itself are arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, merge, nested

I have two nested arrays with equal size:

```
Array1 =[[1, 2], [], [2, 3]]
Array2= [[1, 4], [8, 11], [3, 6]]
```

I need to merge them in one array, like this:

```
Array = [[1,2,1,4], [8,11], [2,3,3,6]],
```

so each elements of new `Array[x] = Array1[x] + Array2[x]`

I understand how to do it with `for(each)` cycle, but I am sure Ruby has an elegant solution for that. It is also possible that the solution will produce by changing  `Array1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Array1, Array2].transpose.map(&:flatten) 
=> [[1, 2, 1, 4], [8, 11], [2, 3, 3, 6]]
```

[RubyGuides: "Turn Rows Into Columns With The Ruby Transpose Method"](https://www.rubyguides.com/2017/10/ruby-transpose-method/)

---

Each step explained:

```
[Array1, Array2]
=> [[[1, 2], [], [2, 3]], 
    [[1, 4], [8, 11], [3, 6]]]
```

Create a grid like array.

```
[Array1, Array2].transpose
=> [[[1, 2], [1, 4]], [[], [8, 11]], [[2, 3], [3, 6]]]
```

[transpose](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) switches rows and columns (close to what we want)

```
[Array1, Array2].transpose.map(&:flatten)
=> [[1, 2, 1, 4], [8, 11], [2, 3, 3, 6]]
```

[flatten](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-flatten) gets rid of the unnecessary nested arrays (here combined with [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-map) to access nested arrays)

Comment: zip method will also do the trick: `Array1.zip(Array2).map(&:flatten)`

Answer (score 4):

```
Array1.each_index.map { |i| Array1[i] + Array2[i] }
  #=> [[1,2,1,4], [8,11], [2,3,3,6]]
```

This has the advantage that it avoids the creation of a temporary array `[Array1, Array2].transpose` or `Array1.zip(Array2)`.

Comment: This answer can also can be easily generalized to more than 2 arrays, or to arrays with more complex (arrays of hashes, etc), while preserving the clarity of the code.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like:

```
array1 =[[1, 2], [], [2, 3]]
array2= [[1, 4], [8, 11], [3, 6]]

array1.zip(array2).map(&:flatten)
# => [[1, 2, 1, 4], [8, 11], [2, 3, 3, 6]]
```

Comment: While a bit wordier, I feel that `array1.zip(array2).map{|a, b| a + b}` better expresses the intent.

Comment: And then we ask ourselves the two questions I've been asking myself for over 15 years: why does `zip` with a block first zip the two elements and then yield the combined array instead of yielding the two elements separately, and why does `zip` with a block act as a side-effecting loop instead of as a transformer. Because then, `Array1.zip(Array2, &:+)` would work, exactly like everybody who uses `zip` the first time *thinks* it would work and is then surprised that it doesn't :-D